# Cronjob to sync comments with disqus with oauth

Tags: oauth, cron, oauth-2.0, disqus

I'm trying to set up a cronjob that syncs comments between Disqus and my database.

Everything is ok with the basic API, but I also need to store Ip addresses and emails in my local db. Reading the documentation, I found out that I need to use oauth and to declare a specific scope in order to get those "confidential" data.

So I set up a script that does everything and it actually works: everything is ok if I access the test page on my browser, trigger the authentication and ALLOW disqus to access my account stuff.

The problem is that I can't do this manually every 10 minutes. I need this to work on a cronjob set up on my linux webserver, but it doesn't work: of course my cronjob can't click on the ALLOW button etc.

Am I missing something? Is this a dumb question? :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your API application includes an administrator's access token (it doesn't expire, so keep this secret!) to perform functions like this, so you don't need to authenticate constantly. So there's two things you need to do:

1. Get your admin access token from your application here (details page): http://disqus.com/api/applications/ - then use this to authenticate in your server-side script.
2. On the same page, go to the settings page and change the default permissions scope from "Read & Write" to "Read, Write & Manage Forums"

This will make sure you get all the sensitive data you need synced up.